# Azure DevOps Gives error access to the path denied

Tags: azure-devops

My below Powershell code is able to successfully upload the artifacts in my SharePoint library. But if I try to loop through my artifacts one by one, it gives me the error

> D:\a\r1\a
> 2020-12-05T14:46:41.3261064Z Get-Content : Access to the path 'D:\a\r1\a\temp' is denied

I would like to know what is causing this error and how can I rectify it?`$workingDir` is `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`.

My current code which works perfect if I remove For-Each line:

```
Function UPLOAD-FILE
{
    param($workingDir, $tempDir, $clientId, $clientSecret, $artifactname)
    CREATE-ARCHIVE -workingDir $workingDir -tempDir $tempDir    
    Write-Host $workingDir 
    Get-ChildItem $workingDir | ForEach-Object {
        $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
        Write-Host $content
    }
    Write-Host $env:System_ArtifactsDirectory+"\KO1" 
    write-host "$SPid"
    write-host "$LibId"
    $file = $workingDir + "\" +$tempDir + "\" + "$($artifactname).zip"
    $fileSize = (Get-Item $file).length
    $uploadURLObject = GET-UPLOADLINK -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret -artifactname $artifactname
    $tokenObject = GET-TOKEN -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
    $uploadHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Range", "bytes " + 0 +"-" + ($fileSize-1) + "/" + $fileSize)
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Length", $fileSize)
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)    
    $uploadBody = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body $uploadBody
    $response | ConvertTo-Json
    REMOVE-TEMPDIR -workingDir $workingDirectory -tempDir $tempDirectory
    return $response        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your loop with

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    Write-Host $content
}
```

The error message indicates that you are trying to use `Get-Content` on something which isn't a file.

Use `Get-ChildItem *.* -rec` if sub-folders should be included.

Comment: and i would be looking to get both files and folder beneath my parent directory

Comment: If I write " Get-ChildItem $workingDir -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
   
    Write-Host $_.FullName} " I get all the items inside folders and sub folders while i just want the first level of folders and files. How do I achieve that.

Comment: The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet gets the items in one or more specified locations. If the item is a container, it gets the items inside the container, known as child items. You can use the `Recurse` parameter to get items in all child containers and use the `Depth` parameter to limit the number of levels to recurse. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1.

Comment: @AnkitKumar How's your issue going? Is it solved?